# MYSQL Delete event is not running

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I have below database tables,

Tables Definition

A - order_dateils :

- id
- order_bar
- description
- payment_status
- created_at

B - invoices :

- id
- invoice_id
- status
- created_at

and created below event to delete data older than 2 months

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT 
IF NOT EXISTS daily_delete 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '020-09-13 04:00:00' 
DO 
BEGIN 
    DELETE 
    FROM bariq_DB.invoice 
    where timestampdiff(MONTH,created_at,NOW()) > 2 and payment_status = 2; 
    delete from bariq_DB.order_details 
    where timestampdiff(MONTH,created_at,NOW()) > 2 and payment_status = 3; 
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

and I checked : `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+------------------+
| Id    | User            | Host      | db        | Command | Time  | State                       | Info             |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+------------------+
|     5 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL      | Daemon  | 61763 | Waiting for next activation | NULL             |
| 34948 | root            | localhost | baridi_DB | Sleep   |   984 |                             | NULL             |
| 34949 | root            | localhost | baridi_DB | Query   |     0 | starting                    | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------------
```

But the events is not deleting any thing that matches the conditions, what Im missing here?

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the event stay put using `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`

```
DELIMITER //
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS daily_delete //
CREATE EVENT 
IF NOT EXISTS daily_delete 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
BEGIN 
    DELETE 
    FROM bariq_DB.invoice 
    where timestampdiff(MONTH,created_at,NOW()) > 2 and payment_status = 2; 
    delete from bariq_DB.order_details 
    where timestampdiff(MONTH,created_at,NOW()) > 2 and payment_status = 3; 
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

See my examples in the following posts

- `Jun 08, 2015` : [Use event schedule and stored procedure to automatically average every hour MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101758/use-event-schedule-and-stored-procedure-to-automatically-average-every-hour-mysq/103507#103507)
- `Jun 08, 2015` : [Choosing what table fields to partition on](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103538/choosing-what-table-fields-to-partition-on/103549#103549)
- `Sep 19, 2014` : [Creating Event that execute at end of each month](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80049/creating-event-that-execute-at-end-of-each-month/80050#80050)
- `Aug 28, 2014` : [Adding time to an event that runs on a weekly basis](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75206/adding-time-to-an-event-that-runs-on-a-weekly-basis/75237#75237)

This will kickoff the event starting midnight tomorrow

You never start an event in the past. You must always start an event in the future.

Comment: @Ronaldo thanks for your help, but its still not deleting from both tables